# How to select and delete words in vim

Tags: vim

I don't get how you are supposed to select words in vim.

In most text editors you can move between words by pressing the control and arrow key, and you can select a section of text, word by word, by using the control and arrow keys with shift.

For instance, in the editor I am using now, if my cursor is at the start of this sentence, and I press shift + ctrl + right arrow, I will select the word 'For'. If I want to delete this word I can then press backspace. I don't understand how you would do this in vim.

Using the same example again, if I were in vim and my cursor was at the start of the above sentence, and I pressed v to go into visual mode and then w to select the first word, the cursor moves to the first letter of the next word, so that if I would press d to delete the word I would delete all of the word 'For' but also the first letter 'i' of the second word.

It seems you cannot select sections of text word by word using w, because the first character of the next word is always selected.

Comment: I would suggest starting with a tutorial, maybe something like https://www.openvim.com/

Comment: But, short answer, `d` followed by a movement command will delete what you're moving over. `dw` deletes a word, `dW` deletes until and including the next space. `de` or `dE` delete to the end of the word or sequence of chars but won't delete the space afterwards. Etc.

Comment: `vimtutor` is another good place to start. And you don't use visual mode nearly as much in Vim as you use selection in other editors. It's just not needed that much.

Comment: Should be migrated to https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you use `evim` then Shift-Ctrl-Right should work automatically.

Comment: @phd with all due respect to both you and OP: question like "I just started using Vim and I don't understand it" won't find much love on Vi and Vim SE either. Doing a little bit of research before asking is a prerequisite on either site.

Comment: @Friedrich But at SO it's offtopic, simple and clear.

Comment: I agree this belongs on vi.stackexchange.com because it is a question about using vim, not a question about writing code. The OP's example is just plain English, not a computer langauge. (If the example were something like "In vim, how do I delete this function block" then I'd think it's ok on both forums.) (I would migrate it myself, but I don't know how and probably also don't have enough reputation.)

Comment: @m_mlvx you miss the point. The question lacks research, therefore it is not suitable for either site. This is a binary property, it cannot be "a little bit unsuitable". Both phd and you want to migrate it to a place where it's "also unsuitable, only less so". This is nonsense. BTW, your reasoning exposes exactly why the "Vim is offtopic" camp is so misguided. If the difference of being on and off-topic is in the words of an example, there really is none.

Comment: @Friedrich I realize the Stack sites prefer some research before questions are asked; but I dispute that "research" is a binary property. The OP found their way to Stack Overflow, which must have involved *some* degree of research -- asking a friend, or typing in Google; something. We can quibble about how much research is *enough* before we permit a neophyte to ask for help. I am inclined to err on the side of generosity, but that may be an unpopular opinion.

Comment: @m_mlvx I wrote that suitability - not research - is binary. Anyhow, I'm delighted to see you want to err on the side of generosity. So do I - that's why I answer Vim questions :-)

Answer (score 2):

> For instance, in the editor I am using now, if my cursor is at the start of this sentence, and I press shift + ctrl + right arrow, I will select the word 'For'. If I want to delete this word I can then press backspace. I don't understand how you would do this in vim.

You would need to *study* something before even fancying "understanding" it.

Vim comes with a very extensive documentation, including a very basic interactive introduction that you can run in your shell, `$ vimtutor` and, once the basics are internalized, a user manual at `:help user-manual`, that is actually more like a very gentle, easy to follow tutorial. Incidentally, "making small changes" is the topic of the 4th chapter of the manual.

Basically, you don't have to wonder or assume things because you have everything at your disposal to learn Vim from first principles. Vim is not an abstract, magical thing. It is something very concrete and very well documented.

The exact section where those things are documented is not important at this pont. What's important is that you follow the user manual and learn Vim correctly instead of counting on your intuition… and on random internet users when your intuition fails you.

> Using the same example again, if I were in vim and my cursor was at the start of the above sentence, and I pressed v to go into visual mode and then w to select the first word, the cursor moves to the first letter of the next word, so that if I would press d to delete the word I would delete all of the word 'For' but also the first letter 'i' of the second word.

`w` means "to next word". It literally moves the cursor to the next word, which is not what you want, therefore it is the wrong tool for the job.

> It seems you cannot select sections of text word by word using w, because the first character of the next word is always selected.

Indeed, you want to visually select "this word" or "the current word", so you want a motion that maps to what you mean. There's `e` (for "end of word"):

```
ved
```

or `iw` (for "inner word"):

```
viwd
```

Note that the two motions only cover the same text *when the cursor is on the first letter of the word*, which is a special case. `e` covers the current word *in some cases* while `iw` *always* covers it, which is why I would recommend `iw` over `e` when you think "this word".

Note also that visually selecting text is rarely needed in Vim. In fact, overusing visual selection is a bit of an anti-pattern. Whenever the text you want to do something to is covered by an existing motion, using the operator+motion mechanism is more direct and precise. In this case, "delete this word" is just a:

```
diw
```

away.

"Linguistically speaking", using visual selection would be akin to saying "Take $OBJECT and do $ACTION to it" to Vim, while using an operator and a motion would be akin to saying "Do $ACTION to $OBJECT". The former is indirect, lower-level, while the latter is direct, higher-level. In general, you want to stay at a high-level as much as possible, and only use low-level stuff when absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'd like to add that `daw` will also remove the whitespace after the word. Which is probably what you want if you delete a word.